# Using ArrayList with sharedpreferences.

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Am trying to store the values in my `ArrayList` with `SharedPreferences` and access them in another class.This is what i have tried so far.

```
public class sample {

final static String file = "myFile";
SharedPreferences fileName;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Sharedpreferences.Editor list = SharedPreferences.edit();
            list.putStringArray("key", 0);
            list.commit();

    }
}

public class sample2 {

String array[] = {"can", "you", "help", "me", "with", "this?"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         Random random = new Random();
         int x;
         x = random.nextInt(5);

         String generatedValue = arr[x];

         String get = fileName.getString("key", 0);
         SharedPreference.Editor editList = SharedPreferences.edit();
         editList.putString("key", get);
         editList.commit();
         }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will get more help asking questions regarding a `problem`.That said,what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to store the values of my string array to the arraylist from the other class using sharedpreferences

Comment: Activities under the same Application package can read the same SharedPreferences file.

Comment: my problem is, I want to store those values in the arraylist permanently, and generate another values not equal to the existing values of the arraylist and store

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) it should tell you everything you need to know about using SharedPreferences.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) is also a perfect example of how to save arraylists in sharedpreferences.Good luck

Comment: `list.putStringArray` ?